# GGplot; two plots in the same graph with the same scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, cowplot

I am calculating the number of mortalities over time (predicted and observed). I tried to visualise two fits with two different ggplots next to each other using the library(cowplot) package. The two ggplots are autoscaled by R on their own data but how do I change the scales so that they both have the same scale (in the Y-axis)?

R script:

```
        # # # ggplot; predicted per capita mortality

dev.off()

c <- ggplot(data=preds, 
       aes(x=DATE, y=1E7*NR_DEATHS/POPULATION)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=factor(YEAR), size=0.5)) +  
  geom_line(aes(y=1E7*NR_DEATHS/POPULATION), colour="red2", size=0.3) +
  ggtitle("PREDICTED TOTAL ALL-CAUSE MORTALITY IN BELGIUM",
          subtitle="data Statbel (pre pandemic data; 2009-2019)") +
  xlab("") + ylab("All-cause mortality\n(per 10M per week)") +
  theme_grey(base_size = 12) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "years" , date_labels = "%Y") +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20)) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 11))

        # # # ggplot; predicted per capita mortality

d <- ggplot(data=mort_by_week, 
            aes(x=DATE, y=1E7*NR_DEATHS/POPULATION)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=factor(YEAR), size=0.5)) +  
  geom_line(aes(y=1E7*NR_DEATHS/POPULATION), colour="red2", size=0.3) +
  ggtitle("OBSERVED TOTAL ALL-CAUSE MORTALITY IN BELGIUM",
          subtitle="data Statbel (pre pandemic + pandemic data; 2009-2022)") +
  xlab("") + ylab("All-cause mortality\n(per 10M per week)") +
  theme_grey(base_size = 12) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "years" , date_labels = "%Y") +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20)) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 11))

plot_grid(c, d)
```

Plot output:
[image: Plot output of the two ggplots of the two fits]

The two different ggplots have a different scale in the Y-axis which makes it difficult to compare the two plots. Is there a way to adjust the scales so that they share the same one?

Comment: Add `+ scale_y_continuous(range = c(1500, 4000))` to each plot.

Comment: Or use `facet_grid()` with `scales = "fixed"` instead of using `cowplot`. However, to do so you'll need to combine the data of `mort_by_week` and `preds` into one data frame.

Comment: Does it matter where I add the "+ scale_y_continuous(range = c(1500, 4000))" to the ggplot script because I added the code above at the end off the ggplot script and my console output was an error?


> Error in scale_y_continuous(range = c(1500, 4000)) : 
  unused argument (range = c(1500, 4000))

Comment: Try: `+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1500, 4000))`